# How connect to mysql with python via odbc

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc, unixodbc

Im  running mysql, pyodbc, python 2.7 loaded on Fedora 14 x64.

Odbcinst.ini is:

```
# Example driver definitions

# Driver from the postgresql-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
#[PostgreSQL]
#Description    = ODBC for PostgreSQL
#Driver     = /usr/lib/psqlodbc.so
#Setup      = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
#Driver64   = /usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so
#Setup64    = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
#FileUsage  = 1


# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
#Driver     = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
#Setup      = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64     = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage   = 1
```

Odbc.ini is :

```
[MySQL]
Driver = MySQL
Database = mysql
Server = localhost
Socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
User = rooter
Password = sshh
```

Mysql.sock is empty? 
/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock has 0.B

python script is:

```
import pyodbc

#pyodbc.pooling = False 
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL};SOCKET=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock;UID=rooter;PWD=sshh') 

csr = conn.cursor()
csr.execute("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON")
csr.close()

conn.close() 
del csr
```

I cant seem to connect with above script, Using isql i get Connected!

MyERROR msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/CCX/Py/MySql Event OFF.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL};SOCKET=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock;UID=rooter;PWD=sshh') 
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

On Win XPx64,

```
#cxn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",user="rooter",passwd ="sshh")
```

Err Msg:

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing `odbcinst.ini` and your `odbc.ini` show an odd value for driver in `odbc.ini`, you should have a dynamic library here (I think).

And why don't you [use direct mysql connection](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html) (without odbc)? :

```
import _mysql

conn = _mysql.connect(host="localhost", user="rooter", 
                      password="sshh", db="mysql") 
conn.query("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON")
conn.close()
```

(not tested)

Comment: above was direct connect with flaws.

Comment: OK, what would be my cxn string?  I got something like: cxn = pyodbc('DSN= MySQL') too work.

Comment: I also want to keep code flexible to use sqlite, mysql, and sybase.

Comment: added a code sample. For the flexibility, you have one query, 4 line of code so..

Comment: @RC, thanks for ur help! I have connection string for both Win XPx64 and Fed 14 via ODBC. On FEd 14, got direct connect via MySQlDb. The breakdown is direct connect using py2.6 on XPx64, its installed but doesnot want to run.

Comment: @user, try to use a 32bits (python + _mysql) on you win64 and see if that helps

Comment: @RC, I updated to 2.6.6, Did a re-install, Prob with registy. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb__init__.py", line 19, in 
    import _mysql
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

if Python26 && windows
   we need download  3 files : libguide40.dll, libmmd.dll, libmySQL.dll
   put the 3 files to C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages 
   and also put the 3 files to C:\Windows\system32
   then restart your system

if Python27 && windows
   when you setup the module ,be careful the version 
   MySQL-python-1.2.3.win32-py2.7.exe
   MySQL-python-1.2.4.win32-py2.7.exe
   one of the 2 version is you need

Answer (score 1):

source: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-mysql-examples

code tested:

```
import _mysql

conn=_mysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="***", db="test")
conn.query("select * from test_table")
result = conn.use_result()

print result.fetch_row()
```

The `fetch_row()` function has two parameters:

1. `maxrows` limits the max number of rows returned.
2. `how`: it returns a tuple when how=0 and returns a dictionary when how=1.

For example, `result.fetch(maxrows=5, how=1)` returns an array (maximum size: 5) of dictionaries where the key is the column name and the value is the column value.